# Apache + PHP: Not finding oci.dll after moving from XP to Win 7

Tags: php, oracle

my PC was upgraded to Win 7. This meant i now need to setup my Dev environment again. I use XAMPP. I was able to just copy & paste XAMPP folder and then run setup_xampp.bat to correctly set absolute file path in ini and config files.

The issue I now face is that I need connection to oracle and I get several errors. But basically php does not "find" oci.dll. I have added the instant_client directory containing oci.dll to PATH environment variable and restarted (restart is required for apache /services to see this change). However I still get the same error.

I then copied oci.dll into php folder and then php.exe -m -> no error. So it is clear that somehow apache and php do not look in PATH variable to find oci.dll. I'm lost as this worked fine in Win XP. Any ideas how I can solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG. The new Win 7 install (this is made by my companies IT support) has per default an oracle 8 client installed which is also in the PATH. Hence the solution is to just remove the entry for this old oracle client so that Apache / php uses the new one.